# What is the proof of Brewster's Law?

Tags: optics

In wave optics, I studied that when unpolarised light is incident on a medium such that the angle between the reflected and refracted ray is $90°$ then the reflected ray is completely polarised and the refracted ray remains partially polarised. This is Brewster's Law. But what is the proof of this? My textbook literally has no reason as to why this is true. Can someone please prove it rigorously usuing mathematics? Even if you cannot prove it, can you at least give some intuition of Brewster's Law? I am so confused. Please help.

Comment: See Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics Chapter 7

Comment: I don't have that book.

Comment: Okay. No problem.

Comment: As you explicitly ask for a mathematical proof I guess the physical explanation with induced dipoles is not what you are looking for?

Comment: @Charles Tucker, you can give a rigorous mathematical proof if possible or at least an explanation through which I can develop some intuition for Brewster's Law.

Comment: @Razor I am really very sorry but I don't have that book.